# iDangero.us Swiper not working when inside a div set hidden display:none

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I want the swiper gallery to show after clicking on a "Show the gallery" link.
But it looks like Swiper is not working properly if initialized inside a hidden div.

Here is my page:

```
<div>
<a href=“javascript:;” onclick=“toggle_visibility('gallery');”><img src=“img.jpg” alt=“Click to open the gallery”></a>
</div>

<div id=“gallery” style:“display:none”>
<!— Swiper —>
<div id=“slide-event” class=“swiper-container swiper-container-event”>
<div class=“swiper-wrapper”>
…
</div>
<!— Add Arrows —>
<div id=“show-hide” class=“swiper-button-next”></div>
<div id=“show-hide” class=“swiper-button-prev”></div>
</div>
<!— End Swiper —>
</div>

<script src="js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>
```

This workaround doesn't work for me:

```
function reinitSwiper(swiper) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   swiper.reInit();
  }, 500);
}
```

Maybe there is another a javascript trick? Any suggestion?

Comment: I've tried with something like this:

$('a').on('click', function reinitSwiper(swiper) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   swiper.reInit();
  }, 500);
});

It doesn't work.

Comment: Well it is easier than this. Just add "observer: true, observeParents: true," to the Swiper initialization.

Comment: It works for me when I add as Frédéric Delaloire said. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I found out these listeners:

```
observer: true
```

observer
Set to true to enable Mutation Observer on Swiper and its elements. In this case Swiper will be updated (reinitialized) each time if you change its style (like hide/show) or modify its child elements (like adding/removing slides)

```
observeParents: true
```

observeParents
Set to true if you also need to watch Mutations for Swiper parent elements

Answer (score 2):

try to call the method

```
swiper.update();
```

when you display the slider